# RIA: Loading entity sets

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria, domainservices

I am missing something very fundamental when working with SL4 RIA entities.
I have a Domain Service with `User` entities.  On the service context, I have a method:

`EntityQuery<User> GetUsersQuery()`

I perform a load like so:

```
context.Load(context.GetUsersQuery(), (loadOp)=> 
{
  // Things done when the load is completed
}, null);
```

When the `Completed` action executes, the `loadOp.Entities` collection is full of the `User` entities, but they are not attached to the `context.Users` entity set.  It also appears that I can't attach them manually from the callback.  What important step am I missing to get these tracked in the entity set?

---

Just to elaborate, in the completed handler, I tried:

```
foreach (var user in loadOp.Entities)
    context.Users.Attach(user);
```

And I get an exception that says an entity with that name is already attached.
Yet, both `context.Users` and `context.EntityContainer` are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are using the same instance of the context in all cases? What does `context.EntityContainer.GetEntitySet<User>().Count` say?

Does `LoadOperation<User>.HasError` return true? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Hah.  You were right on the money.  I didn't realize it but the method that was doing all of that was actually being called twice, so I was looking at two different instances of the context.  Derp!